# Как дополнять json файл не перезаписывая?

Tags: c#, json, файлы

```
FiguresInfo figuresInfo = new FiguresInfo() { Name = parallelepiped.Name, Volume = parallelepiped.CalculateVolume(), Square = parallelepiped.CalculateSquare() };
json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<FiguresInfo>(figuresInfo);
File.WriteAllText(Path, json);
```

Каждый раз когда запускаю код json файл перезаписывается из-за WriteAllText как можно сделать так чтобы каждый запуск сохранялся а последующий дополнял?
Чтобы было типа такого запустил один раз в файле 
{"Name":"Parallelepiped","Volume":45,"Square":118}
 еще запустил только уже с другой фигурой и файл бы дополнился 
 {"Name":"Parallelepiped","Volume":45,"Square":118} 
{"Name":"Cone","Volume":55,"Square":68}

Comment: Никак, в json не существует структуры, которую можно дозаписывать не внося более никаких изменений. А зачем вам это? А вообще есть `AppendAllText`.

Comment: Нужно записать площади и объемы выбранных фигур и записать в файл. Вероятно я не правильно понял и надо сперва собрать все данные в кучу потом записать в файл

Comment: Делаете коллекцию, её и сериализуете в конце заполнения,  а то, что вы хотите, это не json, а ваш собственный формат, ибо то, что показываете как пример, является невалидными данными.

Comment: Нельзя изменить json частично не перезаписывая всё. Но никто не мешает дописывать сколько угодно json-ов в файл и потом вычитывать их. Взять хотя бы тот же json lines.